# How to return the first matched record based on multiple criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I meet a problem that I want to get the return value from another table based on matching multiple criteria. However the matched records could be more than 1, so on this situation I just want to get the first matched record;(for example, first record located on A6, second matched record located A15, so I need A6); here is the sample data:

[image]

I want to get the region from table2, based on following criteria:

1. Table 1!Date.Truck= Table 2!Date+Truck
2. (Table 1!Actual Time>Table 2!Start Time) 
   and (Table 1!Actual Time< Table 2!End Time)

But for example I have 3 rows matched above criteria, but at this situation, I just want the first match, here is (1), so I got New Jersey.

I am trying to write a Array formula with Small function, but it doesn't work:

```
={SMALL(IF((A2='Table 2'!$A:$A)--(D2>'Table 2'!$C:$C)--(D2<'Table 2'!$D:$D),'Table 2'!$B:$B),1)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{=INDEX('Table 2'!$B:$B, MIN(IF(('Table 2'!$A:$A=A2)*('Table 2'!$C:$C<=C2)*('Table 2'!$D:$D>=C2)=1, ROW('Table 2'!$B:$B))), 1)}`

The idea is that `MIN(IF(('Table 2'!$A:$A=A2)*('Table 2'!$C:$C<=C2)*('Table 2'!$D:$D>=C2)=1, ROW('Table 2'!$B:$B)))` gives you the minimum row that qualifies.

`('Table 2'!$A:$A=A2)*('Table 2'!$C:$C<=C2)*('Table 2'!$D:$D>=C2)` gives you the array of 0s and 1s.

Comment: works, should add {}:=INDEX('Table 2'!B:B, MIN(IF(('Table 2'!A:A=A2)*('Table 2'!C:C<=C2)*('Table 2'!D:D>=C2)=1, ROW('Table 2'!B:B))), 1)

Comment: yeh, I ALWAYS forget to tell people array formula