# VLOOKUP With Duplicate Values

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup, lookup, libreoffice-calc

I have 2 sheets like the following:

[image]

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

I want to enter the values ​​from column B on Sheet 2 into column B on Sheet 1.
In Sheet 1 there are some double/duplicate data such as:

*Aek Godang*, dan *Aek Kanopan*

so when I use the formulas:

`=VLOOKUP(A1,$Sheet2.A1:B15,2,1)` or `=INDEX($Sheet2.A1:B15, MATCH(A1,$Sheet2.A1:A15,0),2)`

on row 14 where there is the same data as the previous row, it will always be an error

[image]

how to solve it or the formula so that the result can be like this:

[image]

Comment: Try this and give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the first matched record based on multiple criteria in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706938/how-to-return-the-first-matched-record-based-on-multiple-criteria-in-excel)

Comment: In your Vlookup formula use exact match (last parameter 0).  This will work because your sheet2 data does not contain any duplicates

Comment: @SolarMike, I'm a bit confused by the use of AGGREGATE and COUNTIF there. In my case how to write the correct formula? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

within GS in B1 use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A; Sheet2!A1:B; 2; )))
```

Comment: I get error : Err:504 https://ibb.co/BB2V4dR

Comment: @AndhiIrawan provided solution is for google sheets (as per your tagged question)

Comment: thank you @playerplayer0, yes it works in Google Sheets : https://ibb.co/XjzjgvM

Answer (score -1):

You need only this, enter the formula in cell B1 of sheet 1 and remember to press cse as its an array formula(for excel 2010 till 2019).

```
=SMALL(IF(A1='Sheet2'!A$1:A$15,ROW('Sheet2'!A$1:A$15)),1)
```

[image]

```
=INDEX('Sheet2'!B$1:B$15,SMALL(IF(A1='Sheet2'!A$1:A$15,ROW('Sheet2'!A$1:A$15)),1))
```

The first link given in the comment with countif doesn't work. Aggregate Function is not available in Google Sheet. In Libre office Small function does work.

[image]

With COUNTIF error will be showing, wrong way to resolve.

Comment: If it was entered as a cse, where are the { } that are shown when it is correctly entered?

Comment: @charles-wilkonsin, I've tried your formula : =INDEX('Sheet2'!B$1:B$15,SMALL(IF(A1='Sheet2'!A$1:A$15,ROW('Sheet2'!A$1:A$15)),1)), and it doesn't work. The following display in Microsoft Excel : https://ibb.co/4dk0Wry, and here is how it looks in LibreOffice Calc : https://ibb.co/LCFWkXp. In Google Sheet can't be used. Using this formula : =INDEX(G1:G15,SMALL(IF(A1=F1:F15,ROW(G1:G15),COUNTIF(A1:A1,A1)))), got Err:511